# What are some synonyms for uncriticisable?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms, british-english

I honestly can't think of a word for this. The Cambridge British English dictionary doesn't have it listed as a word, other dictionaries online sometimes have it but don't list synonyms for it. I've tried prefixing *un* to the synonyms of *criticise*, but I end up with similar neologisms like *unchallengeable*.

As I think *uncriticisable* is a bit ugly (and therefore a self referential oxymoron:) would anyone know of there a prettier synonym I can use that is…?

a) in a major British dictionary
b) doesn't need a negation prefixed like *un* or *non* etc

It would be used in the following sentence:

> …including those that support and propogate an unreformed, uncriticisable doctrine.

---

### Edit

Here are the primary sources I used:

1. I used the OSX dictionary and thesaurus. Since it is set to use British English, uncriticisable does not have an entry and unchallengeable has an entry in the dictionary but not in the thesaurus.
2. I used the Cambridge British English dictionary and thesaurus. [Uncritisable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=uncriticisable) is not found. [Uncritiseable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=uncriticiseable) is also not found. [Unchallengeable](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/spellcheck/english/?q=unchallengeable) is not found. Therefore I wasn't going to get any suggestions.
3. I also tried [uncriticizable](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/uncriticizable) but that redirects to *criticize* and you'll note that no antonyms are listed.

Comment: Google Ngrams have instances of 'unchallengeable' dating back to 1800.

Comment: I am voting to leave this question closed as it is for general reference. Also, below answers have enough words.

Comment: @Rathony it fits "Word choice and usage", [from the help centre](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: In order for your question to be **on-topic** for **word choice and usage**, you need to include full context with an example sentence. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: …and yet vote not removed. If there are any *substantial* objections then please raise them, otherwise the close votes should be removed.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks, that's a useful resource and an interesting fact, but it isn't a British English only resource, so not that helpful in this case.

Comment: You've changed the goalposts (and you can always refine a Google Ngram investigation to their British English corpus). I hope you realise that OED say researches English usage worldwide, rather than just British English (whatever that is). // "Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic." @Hot Licks has done a LMGTFY for some reason; a Google search for "unchallengeable synonym" lists the thesaurus.net hit third. As to judging prettiness, that's POB.

Comment: The whole concept of 'unchallengeability' is a philosophical quagmire. If you want a word meaning 'obviously true', there is **apodeictic**  or **apodictic** 
adj
1. unquestionably true by virtue of demonstration
2. (Logic) logic
a. necessarily true
... {[Collins English Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/apodeictic)}. If you want 'held as being incontestible', _The Authority of Scripture_ is the often-used term.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I responded to a request for research, which I did, and a further request to add a sample sentence, which I did. My original question stands, and Googling does not count as an example or an argument as I specified *British English*, (at least add that to the search term). Just close the question if you can't be bothered to apply the rules as they are given on the site, I got what I wanted.

Comment: And finally, read the sample sentence, I'm not looking for "obviously true". So far I'd have downvoted all of your answers, well done you ;)

Comment: The way to approach this is to start with a word that you CAN find in one of the online thesauri, then work through it's list of synonyms (and maybe antonyms) looking for something a little closer.  Then look at the synonyms/antonyms for those words.  It takes some effort.

Comment: @HotLicks I already mentioned what I did, and what I could've done. If checking 2 thesaurus and another online site (found via search engine;) isn't enough, then it's not enough, but I don't need any more snarking from you. Just delete the question and we can all move on with our lives. I would suggest that you use downvotes and not mis-application of the site guidelines to deal with quality problems.

Comment: The point is, start with a word you CAN find, then work outward from there.

Comment: @HotLicks "Perhaps if I'd had more than 3 hours sleep that night I'd have thought to check an American dictionary and thesaurus and work back from there, but I hadn't so I didn't." ;)

Comment: If 'irrefutable' (which is the choice I'd make) is what you have chosen, perhaps you aren't aware that ir- is another prefix indicating negation. Just like un- and non-.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I didn't choose *irrefutable* and wouldn't choose irrefutable because it's to describe a doctrine that I believe to be refutable. Maybe if I said it was *intolerant to refutation* that would help, but having to explain myself any further on this site is losing me the will to continue using StackAnything. Shouldn't you lot be moderating Wikipedia or some other site that is genuinely unfriendly to outsiders? Even the programmers on the other sites are more forgiving, which is a genuinely damning assessment.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.thesaurus.net/unchallengeable:

> absolute, accomplished, certain, commanding, constant, deep-seated,
>   dictatorial, entailed, esoteric, final, firm, fixed, hallowed, holy,
>   immanent, immutable, imperious, implanted, implicit, imprescriptible,
>   inalienable, inarguable, incontestable, incontrovertible,
>   indefeasible, indestructible, indisputable, indubitable, indwelling,
>   infixed, ingrained, inherent, inner, internal, intransferable,
>   intrinsic, invariable, inviolable, inward, inwrought, irreducible,
>   irrefragable, irrefutable, irreversible, non-negotiable,
>   noncontroversial, peremptory, permanent, positive, private, resident,
>   rigid, sacred, sacrosanct, secret, subjective, sure, total, tough,
>   unalienable, unanswerable, unarguable, unassailable, unbreakable,
>   unchanging, unconditional, unconsignable, uncontroversial, undeniable,
>   unnegotiable, untransferable, unvarying.

I kind of like ***sacrosanct***.

Comment: Thank you, my brain got stuck and you unstuck it :) I also think *sacrosanct* is the perfect word for this.

Comment: @iain - A thesaurus is a wonderful thing.

Comment: Many of these include prefixes. And this is genref.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one not listed in HotLicks post:

> **im·mac·u·late**
>
> iˈmakyələt/
>   adjective
>
> 1. perfectly clean, neat, or tidy.
>      "an immaculate white suit"
>      synonyms:   clean, spotless, ultraclean, pristine, unsoiled, unstained, unsullied;
> 2. free from flaws or mistakes; perfect.
>      "an immaculate safety record"
>      synonyms:   unblemished, spotless, impeccable, unsullied, undefiled, untarnished, stainless; More
>      THEOLOGY
>      (in the Roman Catholic Church) free from sin.

Answer (score -1):

From @HotLicks extensive list, consider the 2 synonyms **irrefragable** and **irrefutable**.

> - "irrefragable" definition: impossible to dispute or to contest, e.g. *irrefragable arguments*
> - "irrefutable" definition: that cannot be denied, controverted or disproved, e.g. *irrefutable logic*.

Comment: Both have the prefix ir-.

Comment: Looking at the definitions, almost all words have a "negative" component: [im]possible, [dis]pute, de[ny], [contro]verted, [dis]proved !

Comment: Which makes them inappropriate answers here.